# [Error:System.Net.WebException:Error de la solicitud con el código de estado HTTP 401: Unauthorized.]

Tags: asp.net, reporting

Tengo instalado reporting service 2008 configurado con credenciales básicas
y para poder generar informes debo enviar credenciales configure un pool de aplicación en IIS y a ese pool le di usuario y contraseña con cual logearse en el servidor y este pool se asocio a mi proyecto, aun asi me da este error 
    Error:System.Net.WebException:Error de la solicitud con el código de estado HTTP 401: Unauthorized.

EDIT: el reporting service esta en un servidor externo, este funciona bien ya que desde el mismo servidor se pueden generar, el problema creo yo radica en la comunicacion entre equipo / servidor ya que no esta considerando las credenciales que se envian para la autenticacion

Answer (score 0):

Una de las soluciones es utilizando la siguiente propiedad: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NombreVariable"]` y en el web.config deberías declarar *"NombreVariable"* para su uso:
`<add key="NombreVariable" value="ElValorQueDesees"/>`

El error que tenes ahora se pueden deber a 2 cosas:

1- No tiene acceso la aplicación que estas instanciando en el IIS

2- Problema en el fuente que realizaste. Para la segunda te dejo una solución ejemplo de fuente:

```
public class CustomSSRSCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
{
    private string _SSRSUserName;
    private string _SSRSPassWord;
    private string _DomainName;

    public CustomSSRSCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord, string DomainName)
    {
        _SSRSUserName = UserName;
        _SSRSPassWord = PassWord;
        _DomainName = DomainName;
    }

    public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get { return new NetworkCredential(_SSRSUserName, _SSRSPassWord, _DomainName); }
    }

    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user,
     out string password, out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        user = password = authority = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

En el page_load ,

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
IReportServerCredentials ssrscredentials = new CustomSSRSCredentials("MyUserName", "MyPassword", "ServerName");
ServerReport serverReport = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = ssrscredentials;
serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("ReportPathKey");
serverReport.ReportPath = "/Reports/MyReport";
serverReport.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta sebastian, logre conectarme pero ahora tengo problemas con la autorizacion me da el siguiente error  Error:System.Net.WebException:Error de la solicitud con el código de estado HTTP 401: Unauthorized.
 y lo que es en el reporting service el usuario tiene todo los permisos para la carpeta eh informe

Comment: ¿Podrias poner en donde te da el error? ya que no tengo posibilidades de ver en que momento tenes problemas con la autorización. ¿Lo estas depurando o tenes un localhost o servidor levantado ya?. Sin esa información se me complica mucho ayudarte.

Comment: el servidor donde esta reporting server esta en un servidor externo (no en mi equipo local) y la configuración del mismo "esta bien" ya que se puede generar informes desde "Servidor\reports" el mensaje me da cuando desde mi equipo local intento generar un reporte es una aplicacion web de manera local  la configuración esta en el web.config; nose que otra info te puedo dar que sea de utilidad