# Error de la solicitud con el código de estado HTTP 401: Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, webservice

Basándome en el problema de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227262/errorsystem-net-webexceptionerror-de-la-solicitud-con-el-c%C3%B3digo-de-estado-htt) me encuentro en la misma situación, dispongo de un web service de [report builder](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=6116), se encuentra en el servidor y no puedo acceder desde un cliente.

Para permitirme acceso he seguido [estas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-basic-authentication-on-the-report-server?view=sql-server-2017) instrucciones pero en vano, mi código de conexión es este:

Cadenas de conexion:

```
 private int _commandTimeout = 600;
        private Uri _reportServerUrl = new Uri("http://<Servidor>:80/ReportServer");
        private string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        private ReportViewer _reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
```

función de acceso:

```
 public string CargaInforme(int reportId)
    {
        string nomInforme = "";

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            DataSet reportAccessInfo = SP_RPT_GET_REPORT_INFO(sqlConn, reportId);
            if (reportAccessInfo != null && reportAccessInfo.Tables.Count > 0 && reportAccessInfo.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Uri _reportServerUrl = new Uri(GetReportServer());

                this._reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
                this._reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
                this._reportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;

                DataRow row = reportAccessInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                ServerReport serverReport = this._reportViewer.ServerReport;
                serverReport.ReportServerUrl = _reportServerUrl;                    

                serverReport.ReportPath = (row["reportPath"].ToString().StartsWith("/") ? "" : "/") + row["reportPath"].ToString();                   
                string uriString = row["reportServerPath"].ToString().Trim();
                Uri uri = (Uri)null;
                int num = 0;
                ref Uri local = ref uri;
                if (Uri.TryCreate(uriString, (UriKind)num, out local))
                {
                    serverReport.ReportServerUrl = uri;
                }
                  //Aqui me produce el 401                  
                ReportParameterInfoCollection parameters = this._reportViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters(); 

                if (parameters.Count == 0)
                    this._reportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();                           

                ViewBag.ReportViewer = this._reportViewer;

                nomInforme = row["reportDesc"].ToString();
            }
        }

        return nomInforme;

    }
```

**¿Por qué este error sale en determinados clientes y como puedo solucionarlo?**

**EDIT 1**

El servidor y el cliente se encuentran en el mismo dominio. [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684278/ssrs-2012-report-builder-fails-to-run-from-remote-host-401-unauthorized) tampoco me ha logrado aportar la solución ya que es antigua

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Añadiendo la clase `ReportServerCredentials` y definiendola de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
    {
        private string _userName;
        private string _password;
        private string _domain;

        public ReportServerCredentials(string userName, string password, string domain)
        {
            _userName = userName;
            _password = password;
            _domain = domain;
        }

        public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get
            {
                // Use default identity.
                return null;
            }
        }

        public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get
            {
                // Use default identity.
                return new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password, _domain);
            }
        }

        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user, out string password, out string authority)
        {
            // Do not use forms credentials to authenticate.
            authCookie = null;
            user = password = authority = null;
            return false;
        }
```

Y llamando a esta en la función:

```
serverReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials(_user, _password, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Segun Mozilla [`401`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) significa:

> El código de error HTTP 401 indica que la petición (request) no ha
>   sido ejecutada porque **carece de credenciales válidas de autenticación**
>   para el recurso solicitado.

Por lo que tienes que enviarle las credenciales al servidor utilizando  [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) para que permita consumir el servicio o desactivas la autentificacion que tengas configurado en el IIS y lo cambias a anonima.

Comment: Tienes parte de razón en que me faltaban las credenciales de autentificación, pero la solución que he encontrado es otra.